# VSCode - Browser Preview Set Project Root?

Tags: dynamic, visual-studio-code, preview

How are people setting up live browser preview of PHP pages in VSCode? I have multiple projects with local testing server/web roots like:

http://127.0.0.1/project1/
http://127.0.0.1/project2/
http://127.0.0.1/project2/

etc.....

I just want to simplify previewing dynamic pages for each project - does VSCode support this natively or does it require an extension?